# Html div height not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a php file which shows an ad using Openx. Here i have a list. And at the bottom i need to show  add. but it is in the back. can someone please suggest me to how get add to the front or set height of list as 80% but not in pixels. 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Byrd- Instructional Technology</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none"; });
    </script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="iconapple.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="webapp.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="webapp72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="webapp114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="webapp114.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add2home.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/add2home.js"></script>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainView" height="100%">
        <div data-role="header" id="mainheader">
            <a href="javascript: window.history.go(-1)" data-role="button" data-inline="true"
                data-icon="back" id="backBtn">Back</a>
            <h1 id="linkHeader" style="overflow: visible;">
                Supersites for Elementary</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content" height="100%">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style='overflow: auto; height: 80%;'>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17944&name=Art"
                    class="menu">Art</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17945&name=Bilingual"
                    class="menu">Bilingual</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17946&linkid=nav-menu-original-4-1&name=Computer Smarts!"
                    class="menu">Computer Smarts!</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17947&name=Geography"
                    class="menu">Geography</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17948&name=Organizers & Thinking Maps"
                    class="menu">Organizers & Thinking Maps</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17949&name=Health"
                    class="menu">Health</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17950&name=Holidays"
                    class="menu">Holidays</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17951&name=Keyboarding"
                    class="menu">Keyboarding</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17952&name=Math"
                    class="menu">Math</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17953&name=Music"
                    class="menu">Music</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17954&name=PE"
                    class="menu">PE</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=18575&linkid=nav-menu-original-4-1743&name=Prek and Kinder"
                    class="menu">Prek and Kinder</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17956&name=Reading/LA"
                    class="menu">Reading/LA</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=18489&linkid=nav-menu-original-4-1743&name=Science"
                    class="menu">Science</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17927&linkid=nav-menu-original-4-1743&name=Social Studies"
                    class="menu">Social Studies</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17960&name=SMARTboard"
                    class="menu">SMARTboard</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17961&name=TAKS"
                    class="menu">TAKS</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=17962&name=Thinking Games"
                    class="menu">Thinking Games</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?cms_mode=view&sectiondetailid=18532&linkid=nav-menu-original-4-1743&name=Cool Websites"
                    class="menu">Cool Websites</a></li>
                <li class="link3"><a href="frame_url.php?url=http://www.azleisd.net/education/components/scrapbook/default.php?sectiondetailid=18808&#gotonew&name=Counseling Corner"
                    class="menu">Counseling Corner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->
    </div>
    <div align="center" id="placeholder">
        <script type='text/javascript'><!--            //<![CDATA[
            var m3_u = (location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://ad.educatorsapp.com/www/delivery/ajs.php' : 'http://ad.educatorsapp.com/www/delivery/ajs.php');
            var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999);
            if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
            document.write("<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + m3_u);
            document.write("?zoneid=1");
            document.write('&cb=' + m3_r);
            if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write("&exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
            document.write(document.charset ? '&charset=' + document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&charset=' + document.characterSet : ''));
            document.write("&loc=" + escape(window.location));
            if (document.referrer) document.write("&referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
            if (document.context) document.write("&context=" + escape(document.context));
            if (document.mmm_fo) document.write("&mmm_fo=1");
            document.write("'><\/scr" + "ipt>");
       //]]>--></script>
        <noscript>
            <a href='http://ad.educatorsapp.com/www/delivery/ck.php?      n=a60641fc&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE'
                target='_blank'>
                <img src='http://ad.educatorsapp.com/www/delivery/avw.php?  zoneid=1&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&n=a60641fc'
                    border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

An ad will show here. It needs to get to the front or i need to reduce the height of list div tag. This is for a responsive website.

Comment: Please reduce your code to only what's relevant to your question.

Comment: <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"  style='overflow:auto; height:80%;'> This hight not working

Comment: http://educatorsapp.com/educators/byrdit/sub_home.php. this is example

Comment: As a side not, you should try to avoid inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

Height by percentage only works if the height of the parent element is set.  You can either set the height of the parent, or use something like jQuery's .height() to find the height of the parent, and calculate/add the height to your ul. For the height documentation, you can find it at http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Unless the element is absolutely positioned, in that case it will work even without setting the parent height.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place your ad in the front, you may need to add to your #placeholder

`z-index: 20;`

z-index will allow you to control at what level you need to place a container or element in terms of dept. The lower the number, the more deep it appears. The higher the number, more to the front it appears.